# Como passar os dados de um formulário HTML para um objeto php

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Bom dia,

Nos artigos passados que eu escrevi estava mencionando que estava aprendendo Orientação a Objetos no PHP na própria documentação, e agora resolvi fazer alguns testes que talvez possam ser aplicados na vida real, porém não houve sucesso.

Eu criei uma classe no PHP chamada Pessoa e um formulário html, só que quando eu chamo o método de apresentar ele não consegue resgatar os dados que foram passados.

```
class Pessoa {

    public $nome;
    public $idade;
    public $sexo;
    public $qualidade;
    public $defeito;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->idade = $idade;
        $this->sexo = $sexo;
        $this->qualidade = $qualidade;
        $this->defeito = $defeitos;

    }

    public function apresentacao() {

        echo("Olá! Meu nome é! $this->nome, eu possuo $this->idade anos.<br/>Sou do Sexo: $this->sexo");

    }


}

//Aqui é feito um teste para verificar se estava sendo pego realmente, está tudo ok!

echo $nome = $_POST['nome'];
echo $idade = $_POST['idade'];
echo $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
echo $qualidade = $_POST['qualidade'];
echo $defeito = $_POST['defeito'];


$pessoa1 = new Pessoa();
$pessoa1->apresentacao();
```

#### Formulario HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="Animal.php">

    <input type="text" class="" id="" name="nome">
    <input type="text" class="" id="" name="idade">
    <input type="text" class="" id="" name="sexo">
    <input type="text" class="" id="" name="qualidade">
    <input type="text" class="" id="" name="defeito">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>

</form>
```

Edit1: O meu intuito não é aplicar nenhuma norma avançada (tipo organização de arquivo, classes separadas, etc) eu só gostaria de ver onde eu estou errando, o meu objetivo é compreender o que falta, o que estou fazendo e o que foi em excesso.

Edit2: O erro que está dando no meu PHP na hora de mostra é: que as variaveis não foram definidas.

Edit3: Não era para quando eu chamar o método `apresentar()` ele já pegasse e organizasse?

> Notice: Undefined variable: nome in line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: idade in line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: sexo in line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: qualidade in line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: defeitos in line 19

Comment: `echo $nome = $_POST['nome']`, o que esta linha deveria fazer?

Comment: Lembrando que isso é só um teste (o arquivo inteiro), mas essa linha indicaria para verificar se estava realmente pegando os dados do formulário.

Comment: Principalmente por se tratar de um teste que o código deveria representar a realidade da pergunta. Você fez um `echo` e uma atribuição de variável na mesma linha. Isso fez sentido para você? Qual seria o resultado esperado nessa linha, isto é, o que deveria ser exibido pelo `echo` e qual deveria ser o valor de `$nome` após executar a linha?

Comment: Realmente não tenha feito muito sentido, obrigado pela observação. Respondendo sua pergunta, seriam os dados do formulário, talvez não tenha entendido muito bem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que você não está passando as variáveis para o construtor da classe, por isso elas não existem.
Tente fazer assim:

```php
public function __construct($nome, $idade, $sexo, $qualidade, $defeitos) {

        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->idade = $idade;
        $this->sexo = $sexo;
        $this->qualidade = $qualidade;
        $this->defeito = $defeitos;

    }
```

E passe os dados do formulário para a classe:

```php
echo $nome = $_POST['nome'];
echo $idade = $_POST['idade'];
echo $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
echo $qualidade = $_POST['qualidade'];
echo $defeito = $_POST['defeito'];


$pessoa1 = new Pessoa($nome, $idade, $sexo, $qualidade, $defeito);

$pessoa1->apresentacao();
```

Comment: Opa! Deu certo @AlexsanderSS, mas fiquei em dúvida agora, quando vi na documentação do PHP ele não passava os parâmetros dentro dos () no construtor, poderia me explicar o pq devo passar? Igual em new Pessoa

Comment: Quando você faz ```$this->nome = $nome``` significa que a variável ```$nome``` do objeto que está sendo instanciado (nesse caso ```pessoa1```) vai receber o valor da variável ```$nome``` do construtor que até então não existia pois não tinha sido declarada. Já quando você passa para o ```new Pessoa``` você está passando o valor da variável ```$nome``` para o construtor, para quê então seja passado o valor para a variável do objeto. Resumindo: o valor de ```$nome``` é passado para o construtor da classe, que então passa para a a variável do objeto.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, o problema no método construtor da sua classe:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->nome = $nome;
    $this->idade = $idade;
    $this->sexo = $sexo;
    $this->qualidade = $qualidade;
    $this->defeito = $defeitos;
}
```

Você está atribuindo aos campos do seu objeto as variáveis `$nome`, `$idade`, `$sexo`, `$qualidade` e `$defeitos`, mas essas variáveis não existem no escopo. Imagine o método/função como uma caixa preta. Nela você só pode trabalhar com aquilo que você **explicitamente** coloca na caixa. Não tem como você acessar uma variável dentro do método que você não adicionou **explicitamente** ao escopo do método. As variáveis que você definiu fora da classe até possuem o mesmo nome, mas estão definidos em escopos diferentes e não possuem relação alguma entre si.

Se percebeu bem, a palavra central é: **escopo**. Estude mais a fundo como o PHP gerencia os escopos e quando entender bem essa parte você conseguirá resolver sozinho a grande maioria dos problemas que encontrar pela frente. Sabendo manipular os escopos da linguagem a seu favor te dá uma vantagem muito grande sobre a linguagem e entendê-los como funciona é parte fundamental para utilizá-la corretamente.

A forma mais fácil de importar uma variável externa para um escopo interno é através dos parâmetros da função. Isto é, se você possui cinco variáveis fora da classe e precisa passar para dentro do método, então precisará definir os parâmetros:

```
public function __construct($nome, $idade, $sexo, $qualidade, $defeitos) {
    $this->nome = $nome;
    $this->idade = $idade;
    $this->sexo = $sexo;
    $this->qualidade = $qualidade;
    $this->defeito = $defeitos;
}
```

Ao estudar sobre escopos você, cedo ou tarde, cruzará com a diretiva `global`, que também serve para importar variáveis externas a um escopo interno, mas adianto que ela não serve para este exemplo.

Além disso, como os campos da sua classe possuem a visibilidade pública, você pode definir os respectivos valores diretamente:

```
$pessoa = new Pessoa();

$pessoa->nome = $nome;
$pessoa->idade = $idade;
$pessoa->sexo = $sexo;
$pessoa->qualidade = $qualidade;
$pessoa->defeitos = $defeitos;
```

Porém, perceba que desta forma nenhum parâmetro é passado para o método na inicialização da classe. Na verdade, ao fazer isso, você nem precisaria um construtor definido:

```
class Pessoa {

    public $nome;
    public $idade;
    public $sexo;
    public $qualidade;
    public $defeito;

    public function apresentacao() {
        echo("Olá! Meu nome é! $this->nome, eu possuo $this->idade anos.<br/>Sou do Sexo: $this->sexo");
    }

}
```

Mas há razões bem definidas para que as pessoas evitem fazer desta maneira e, para resumir, porque não há como garantir que o objeto será criado em um estado válido - com o método construtor sim, dada que é exatamente essa a responsabilidade dele.

Outro detalhe é que, embora funcione normalmente, fazer `echo $nome = $_POST['nome']` não faz sentido algum. Em uma linha de código você faz a atribuição à uma variável e a exibe como forma de debug. Uma linha de código com duas responsabilidades. Evite fazer isso. Se a ideia era somente verificar se o que foi digitado no formulário está chegando corretamente, faça algo como:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$idade = $_POST['idade'];
...

var_dump($_POST);
```

Assim já verá tudo o que chegou no PHP a partir do formulário. Outra forma bem melhor do que essa é configurar o seu servidor para trabalhar com ferramentas de debug, como o xDebug. Com essa ferramenta você consegue analisar os valores e contextos em todo o seu código sem ter que ficar modificando-o para exibir na página.

Comment: Me surpreendi pela resposta @Anderson Carlos Woss, acabou esclarecendo bastante coisa que fiquei em dúvida, pois estou iniciando nesse mundo web "atualmente", e não sei muito bem as boas e más práticas que devo aplicar, estou seguindo a documentação pura então as vezes acabo me perdendo.